# Only execute the last Ajax call during simultaneous calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I'm making a search engine using Elasticsearch and autocomplete when an user search something in a text input.

My JS code work perfectly but it send a new Ajax call every added or removed character if there are more than 3.

So I'm trying to deny all previous Ajax calls and only execute the last sent.

My JS code look like this right now

```
class @SearchEngine
    search: ->
        @searchInput = $('.search-input')
        @minChar = 3
        @actionUrl = $('.search-form').attr('action')
        @tbody = $('#tbody')

        @searchInput.on 'keyup', =>
            @query = @searchInput.val()

            if (@minChar <= @query.length)
                $.ajax
                    url: @actionUrl
                    type: 'GET'
                    data: {
                        search: @query
                    }
                .done (data) =>
                    if data?
                        @tbody.html data
                        momentFromNow()
```

Is there a way to deny all previous Ajax call and then execute the last one ?